# How to validate all the fields at once by making a default validator in django restframework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, flask-restful

I don't want to use Field level or object level validation. While doing POST API call in django restframework, I want to call a default validator by **is_valid()** method. No arguments should be passed while calling this method and all the fields should be validated.
**It should be fully generic, so that I can add as many validations as possible.**

Comment: Where do you intend to call this validation

Comment: I want to put this validation function in the serializers.py and call this from views.py (using is_valid() func while doing POST call)

user_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
user_serializer = UserDataSerializer(data=user_data)
if user_serializer.is_valid():
     user_serializer.save()

Comment: is object level validation is the solution?

Comment: Yes that should do the trick. Specifically by overriding `validate` (object level validation)